# Boost Log Formatter Using the same string as in keyword

Tags: c++, logging, boost, formatting

Here is how I set up my loggers:

```
namespace logger = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
using LEVEL = boost::log::trivial::severity_level;


static void log_Severity(LEVEL level, sender_t sender, std::string message);
static void throw_Severity(LEVEL level, sender_t sender, std::string message);
static std::string getUnescaped(std::string input);
static std::string format(sender_t sender, std::string message);;
static std::string HRESULTSTRING(HRESULT result);

typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;

static std::string CreateFormat()
{
    logger::add_common_attributes();
    logger::register_simple_formatter_factory< LEVEL, char >("Severity");
    return "[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%";
}

static void AddTerminalLogger(std::string format)
{
    auto sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter()));
    sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
    //sink->set_formatter( format );
    logger::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

static void AddFileLogger(std::string path, std::string format)
{
    logger::add_file_log
        (
        logger::keywords::file_name = path + "ManualTest_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%N.log",
        logger::keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        logger::keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        logger::keywords::format = format
        );
}

static void SetLogLevel(LEVEL level)
{
    logger::core::get()->set_filter(logger::trivial::severity >= level);
}

void LogHelper::SetupLoggers(std::string path)
{
    std::string format = CreateFormat();
    AddFileLogger(path, format);
    AddTerminalLogger(format);
    SetLogLevel(LEVEL::trace);
}
```

I want to use my existing format string to set up my console logging as well.
How can I reuse `"[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"` so I do not repeat myself when I create my format expression?

Edit:
To clarify: This is not valid as far as I know: `sink->set_formatter(expr::format("[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"));` If I wanted to use set_formatter I would have to write an expression that does the same thing as this `logger::keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"`. If I do so I would use one approach per logger (Terminal, File) to hopefully get the same formatting in both. Both loggers are a sink that is added to the core. So i assume the method `logger::add_file_log` uses something like `set_formatter` under the hood. I would like to use the capabilities that are built in somewhere that would allow me to apply the string `"[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"` to a sink. I can not find the documentation though. When I look this topic up I do find how to use set_formatter but it always ends up in developing something different that gets the same result. I feel this introduces error potential since I would just repeat myself in the sense that I would rewrite the formatting I want in my logging just with slight variations.

Edit:
Changed the source code to better reflect the question.

Comment: Make it a global constant or a #define? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, i should refine my question, this is not about how to pass things as parameters. This is about how an expression is way more complicated than the logger keyword. I would like to use one way of doing this rather than maintaining two ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use [`add_console_log`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.convenience) function similarly to how you use `add_file_log` in your code.

Second, both these functions use the [formatter parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.filter_formatter) (the `parse_formatter` function) to convert the format string to the actual formatter you can supply to `set_formatter`. You can use this function directly to avoid parsing the string multiple times.